# Cannot launch Vault from Helm on kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, hashicorp-vault

I'm trying to follow along the Hashicorp docs to set up a Vault instance

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_r368h-mxxs&t=94s
https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/platform/k8s/helm/run/

To start of with the initialisation I run

```
helm --namespace=myvault --name=vault .
```

But when I try to initialise the Vault instance itself with

```
kubectl --namespace=vault exec -it vault-0 -- vault operator init
```

I get the error

```
Error from server (BadRequest): pod vault-0 does not have a host assigned
```

Running

```
kubectl --namespace=vault describe pods vault-0
```

gives the error

```
Warning  FailedScheduling  60s (x21 over 10m)  default-scheduler  pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims (repeated 3 times)
```

Is there a setting that I'm missing and not shown in the docs that needs set for this to work?

Running on prem Centos 7 cluster with 3 nodes

Comment: Updated with the environment setup

Answer (score 2):

Vault is deployed as StatefulSet which has `volumeClaimTemplates`

```
volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      name: data
    spec:
      accessModes:
      - ReadWriteOnce
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 10Gi
      volumeMode: Filesystem
```

It seems for some reason the PVC and PV is not created and the pod needs to be bound to a PVC before it can be started. Below commands should give some clue.

```
kubectl describe pvc
kubectl describe pv
kubectl describe sc
```

If there is no default storage class you may need to create it so that the PersistentVolumeClaim can take the storage from there